# The Kähler form and the anticanonical line bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, mirror-symmetry

Let $M$ be a Kähler manifold. We say that $M$ is Fano if the anticanonical line bundle $K_M^*$ of $M$ is ample (or positive).

On the other hand, I sometimes see the following definition (or sufficient condition) especially in the context of mirror symmetry.

Define the effective cone of $M$ by
$$K(M) := \lbrace \phi_*[C] \in H_2(M,\mathbb Z) \mid C\ \text{curve}, \phi:C \to M \rbrace.$$
If the Kähler form $\omega$ is positive on $K(M)$, then $M$ is Fano.

**Question: How do we see that the positivity of $\omega$ on $K(M)$ implies (or is equivalent to) the Fano property?**

In particular I want to know the relation between the anticanonical bundle $K_M^*$ and the Kähler form $\omega$.

Comment: Something looks strange with your stated criterion, in that neither $K(M)$ (homology classes of curves in $M$) nor the Kähler form depend on the anticanonical class. This may be a long shot, but perhaps you're looking for [Kleiman's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ample_line_bundle#Intersection_theory), and the intended condition is something like "the anticanonical class is positive on $K(M)$"...?

Comment: I believe you're looking for the Nakai-Moishezon Criterion, but I'm not sure how your Kahler form and canonical line bundle are related. For example, abelian varieties have positive Kahler forms but trivial canonical bundles.